# Select all records that don't exist in another table Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, i'm trying to select a number of records if they don't already exist in another table.
I have three models, **Lead**, **SalesLog** and **Cron** and the idea is to get all leads that are not already in the SalesLog and where the `created_at` field is greater than or equal to than the **Crons** `duplicated_days` field.

So far have something that looks like this, but it's not working at all

```
    $leads = Lead::whereIn('status', [$minimumRequiredStatus])->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use ($cron) {

        $query->table('sales_log')->select(['id'])->where('campaign', $cron->campaign);

    })->get();
```

I can use filters for this but i might eventually be working with thousands and possibly millions of records on both the `leads` and `sales_log` tables.. This makes me apprehensive about doing it offline.

How could i run a query that would simply get all `leads` that are of the required status, not already inside of the `sales_log` and whose `created_at` field is equal to or greater than, say 30 days for instance.

This version with the Filters actually works the way it's expected to, but i fear the performance impact of such an operation with several records on both tables.

```
    $leads = $cron->campaign->validLeads->filter(function($lead) use ($cron) {

        if($cron->salesLogs->contains(SalesLog::LEAD_ID, $lead->{Lead::ID}))
            return false;

        return true;

    });
```

As far as Models are concerned i have 4 models that should be used here, a **Lead** model that refers to a `leads` table that contains leads for *every campaign* a **Campaign** Model, a **Cron** model that contains all Crons that **Belong to** a Campaign.
Finally there's a **SalesLog** model, all leads, once sent via CURL get added to this Table, this is how i can tell which leads were sent and to which **Campaign**

So, to recap

**Campaign** is the top-level Model it has access to the **Lead** model and the **Cron** model via a *hasMany* relationship.

**Lead** is the model for the table where **ALL** leads are stored. Regardless of Campaigns. It *belongs to* a **Campaign** and *has many* **SalesLog**

The **Cron** also *belongs to* a **Campaign** and *has many* **Sales Log** through another Model.

Finally, the **SalesLog** *belongs to*  a **Campaign** and also *belongs to* a **Lead**

So the idea is through the **Cron** i can access all **SalesLogs** for that Cron, and i need to get all **Leads** from a **Campaign** where the Lead's **ID** is not in the **SalesLogs** for that **Campaign**

Comment: Have you tried `Eloquent: hasNot() method`?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i'm not finding the Documentation for that Method, can you please provide me a link?

Comment: [Request Link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3413). This is GIT request link. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't a left join suffice?

```
$leads = Lead::whereIn('status', [$minimumRequiredStatus])
             ->leftJoin('sales_log', function ($join) use ($cron) {
                 $join->on('leads.id', '=', 'sales_log.lead_id')
                      ->where('sales_log.campaign_id', '=', $cron->campaign->campaign_id);
             })
             ->whereNull('sales_log.id')
             ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
             ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your help, however it's not quite working, it's returning more leads than it should, i'm expecting 23 back (1 should be excluded) and it's returning over 70 (from every Campaign) even after i add 

`->where('leads.campaign_id', $cron->campaign->campaign_id)` 

into the mix. I have another version with the Filters (which ill add to the Question), that one works, but am i right in fearing the performance hit?

Comment: It's much more efficient to do this via queries than by manipulating objects in PHP, especially if you expect them to be in the order of millions, so yes, you should have a performance hit with your working version. Can you share more about your two tables structure?

Comment: would the Models relationships suffice? What exactly do you need?

I'll add the relationships to the Question for this particular problem

Comment: I've added an explanation of the Models i have and their relationships to each other. If you need anything else please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck` for getting the id's which will not present in another table, follow below instructions,

`$unapproved = $this->approval->where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('approved_by')->all();`


`$unapproved = $this->company->whereNotIn('id', $unapproved)->with('countries')->get();`